# how to subtract one column data from 2nd row to 1st row in csv files using python

Tags: python, csv

I have CSV file with data like

```
data,data,10.00
data,data,11.00
data,data,12.00
```

I need to update this as

```
data,data,10.00
data,data,11.00,1.00(11.00-10.00)
data,data,12.30,1.30(12.30-11.00)
```

could you help me to update the `csv file` using python

Answer (score 0):

You can use `pandas` and `numpy`. `pandas` reads/writes the csv and `numpy` does the calculations:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
data = pd.read_csv('test.csv', header=None)

col_data = data[2].values
diff = np.diff(col_data)
diff = np.insert(diff, 0, 0)
data['diff'] = diff

# write data to file
data.to_csv('test1.csv', header=False, index=False)
```

when you open `test1.csv` then you will find the correct results as you described above with the addition of a zero next to the first data point.

For more info see the following docs:

- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html
- http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html